# How to add multithreading in the Spider Crawler in python?

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, urllib2

I have written a Spider Crawler using BeautifulSoup and urllib2. This parses all the links upto 2 levels and collects all the html pages in a list. I tried making it multithreaded to add a little pace to the Spidering process however couldn't figure out where to begin ?

Below is the code.

#

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import urllib2
import sys

masterList = []
masterList1 = []
htmlList = []
url = "http://www.securitytube.net"
dictList = []

def spidy(url):
            try:
                    page = urllib2.urlopen(url)

                    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())
                    if soup:

                            for links in soup.findAll('a',href=True):

                                    ele = links['href']

                                    if ".html" in ele and "http://" in ele:
                                            htmlList.append(ele)
                                            print ele


                                    elif ".html" in ele and "https://" in ele:
                                            htmlList.append(ele)
                                            print ele

                                    else:
                                            masterList.append(ele)


                    for ele in masterList:
                            if 'mailto:' in ele:
                                    masterList.remove(ele)

            except:
                    print "url %s is not accessible ... Moving on to the next URL .."%(url)
                    pass

def level():
    masterList1 = list(set(masterList))
    for url1 in masterList1:

            print "Running Spidy on : %s"%(url1)
            print "\n########################################################\n"

            spidy(url1)

            print "\n########################################################\n"
            masterList1.remove(url1)


            masterList.remove(url1)

def main():
    spidy("http://www.securitytube.net")
    level()
    level()
    print "\n\n\n\n\n********************************************************************"
    print htmlList
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever heard of [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/)?

Its super easy to create a simple spider with this and people have been developing it for years. It is not exactly multithreaded but it uses Twisted on the background so it is completely asynchronous and event-based.

Comment: I'll have a look into it. Thanks.